# Finding essential ideal in a ring $R$

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring and let $L$ be a left ideal of $R$. The left ideal $L$ is said to be essential if $L \cap S \neq \lbrace 0 \rbrace$, for any non-zero left ideal $S$ of $R$.

Now let $L$ be a random left ideal of $R$. I have to show that there exists a left ideal $L'$ of $R$ such that $L \cap L' =\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ and $L \oplus L'$ is an essential ideal of $R$.

Any tips?

Comment: I would go for a *maximal* $L'$ which is disjoint to $L$, using Zorn lemma..

Comment: Using Zorn's lemma, I have found a maximal element $M$ of the set $P=\lbrace I \mid I \text{ideal and} I \cap L = (0) \rbrace$. If I take $L'=M$, then the first condition holds. For the second condition, if $S$ is a non-zero left ideal of $R$, then there are two options: $S \cap L \neq \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ (in this case $L \oplus L' \cap S \neq \lbrace 0 \rbrace$) and $S \cap L = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$. In this case we have that $S \in P$. How do I continue from here?

Answer (score 1):

> then there are two options: $S∩L≠\{0\}$ (in this case $L⊕L′∩S≠\{0\}$) and $S∩L=\{0\}$. In this case we have that $S∈P$. How do I continue from here?

You're basically right on top of the answer. You've already chosen $L'$ to be maximal (in your comment).  If $L\oplus L'\cap S=\{0\}$, then $L\oplus L'\oplus S$ is direct as well.

So $L'\oplus S\in P$, not merely $S$.

Now do you see the contradiction?

Comment: Then $L' \oplus S= L'$, by the maximality of $L'$ and we're done.

Comment: @J.Bosser Well, if by "done" you mean "we have reached a contradiction", then yes.

Comment: I have a more general question. The definition of a direct sum of two ideals is clear to me. But if one writes  $\oplus_{i \in I}J_i$, a 'general' direct sum of ideals, does this mean that $J_i \cap J_j = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$, for $i,j \in I$?

Comment: @J.Bosser NO, it is much stronger than that. It means that $(\sum_{i\neq j} I_j)\cap I_j=\{0\}$ for every index $j$.  It is easy to formulate a counterexample in $\mathbb R^2$ that has the property you mention, but which is obviously not a direct sum.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I'm still a little bit confused. First you say that the sum $L \oplus L' \oplus S$ is direct. As a consequence, $(L' \oplus S )\cap L = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$. But isn't that one of the conditions you need to check in order to say that the sum $L \oplus L' \oplus S$ is direct?

Comment: @J.Bosser Hm? What I said is still there: "If $L\oplus L'\cap S=\{0\}$, then $L\oplus L'\oplus S$ is direct as well."  So no, I did not say the sum was direct first, and then as a consequence the intersection is trivial.  Quite the opposite.

Comment: Okay, I think I misunderstood. As you mentioned before, the condition for a sum to be direct is $(\sum_{i \neq j} I_i) \cap I_j =\lbrace 0 \rbrace$. This sum $\sum_{i \neq j}I_i$ does not need to be direct, right?

Comment: @J.Bosser It is necessarily direct. But the fact that it is direct is immaterial to checking the condition...